# Setting up continuing reinforcement learning environments using MATLAB's RLToolbox

Tags: matlab, environment, reinforcement-learning

I want to create a continuing (non-episodic) reinforcement learning environment. As my environment is in Simulink, I am hoping to use MATLAB's RLToolbox. There are some tutorials focusing on creating environments for the episodic cases, however I couldn't find one for the non-episodic case.

The main concern is how we define the "isdone" variable, as in the case of non-episodic environment there are no terminating states.

From what I believe the "isdone" variable should be always be `false` so that the environment can continue forever. Am I correct?. But from a practical standpoint there should be some terminating point even for non-episodic cases as things such as  performance indicators must eventually be measured (I might be wrong on this !)

If so how do define a termination criteria in non-episodic cases that will eventually stop? or does it happen from the algorithm side (i.e RLAgent terminates when perhaps  the optimal policy (q -> q*) is found?

Another issue is what would you pass to the environment reset function? Would this be an empty value?

Any knowledge on this much appreciated as I am just starting out RL.

Thanks